# Why does preload callback is not parsed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I am trying to check auto updates on electron app. But my callbacks are not working. Here are important parts of my code.

**updater.ts**

```
export default class Updater {
  mainWindow: BrowserWindow;

  constructor(mainWindow: BrowserWindow) {
    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
  }

  showMessage(message: String) {
    console.log('showMessage trapped');
    console.log(message);
    this.mainWindow.webContents.send('updateMessage', message);
  
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    show: false,
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: app.isPackaged
        ? path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        : path.join(__dirname, '../../.erb/dll/preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  });


  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'undocked' });
  updater = new Updater(mainWindow);

};


app
  .whenReady()
  .then(() => {
    createWindow();
    app.on('activate', () => {
      if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
    });

    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    updater?.showMessage('Checking for Updates');
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

**preload.ts**

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, IpcRendererEvent } from 'electron';
const updateApp = {
  updateMessage: (callback: any) => {
    console.log("Preload");
    ipcRenderer.on('updateMessage', callback);
  },
};


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('update', updateApp);
```

**App.tsx**

```
export default function App() {
  let msg:String;
  useEffect(() => {
    window.update.updateMessage(updateMessage);
  }, []);
  const updateMessage = (e: any, message: String) => {
    console.log('updateMessageCallback');
    console.log(message);
    console.log('message logged in view');
  };
  const showPopUp = () => {
    window.my_modal_1.showModal();
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
      <StartingPopUp showPopUp={showPopUp} />
      <TitleBar />
      <UpdateNotification message={msg} />
      <Navbar />
      <Logo />
      <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 p-6">
        <CommandsContainer />
      </div>
      <Progress />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It logs
*showMessage trapped
Checking for Updates*
to the console. Those are from the method from updater class.
Then it logs
*Preload*
to the console. This is from the `updateMsg` from **updateApp ** Bridge.
It works correct until Preload function. It logs "Preload" into the console. But the callback function not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your renderer is ready and loaded when you call `updater.showMessage`?

Comment: @Arkellys I think so. If not how to get around it?

Comment: @Arkellys Thank you so much bro.. That was the problem.. Got around it with `mainWindow.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => {updater?.showMessage});`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was my renderer wasn't ready when I call `updater?.showMessage()`. So, The solution is wait till the renderer is ready. That can be done by doing this.

```
mainWindow.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => {updater?.showMessage});
```

Comment: Glad you found a fix, but I think you made a typo? It should be either `updater?.showMessage()` or `mainWindow.webContents.once('did-finish-load', updater?.showMessage);`